# angular 2 - get information from active component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I've got a page with a header and a body. The header has a HELP button, that's supposed to open documentation. The link to documentation is parametrized by a *help-id*, which depends on which page is currently displayed.

I need to have updated *help-id* in header depending on which component is currently being displayed by a router. In other words, what is the correct way of getting this parameter (which is a simple string) from currently active component?

I've seen the communication being done using a service, but it seems creating a service for such a simple task is a a bit of an overkill.

I've tried to deduce something from Router and ActivatedRoute code, but I was unable to get anything working. The navigation events do not hold any reference to component, `routerState.root.firstChild` is null when the app is loaded.

EDIT:

here, in the `AppComponent` I need the current *help-id*

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  private helpId;
}
```

My components that are displayed in router-outlet have this property, e.g.

```ts
export class HeroComponent {
  const helpId = 'hero';
}

export class HeroDetailsComponent {
  const helpId = 'hero-details';
}
```

There are routes defined for each component, for example

```
const heroesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes',  component: HeroComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailsComponent }
];
```

I need the *help-id* of currently displayed component (rendered by the router) in order to keep the help link in header up-to-date. The *help-id* is not passed in route params.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, allows to reproduce and diagnose the issue.

Comment: What if there are more than one component displayed? The question needs more context. How and when are the components displayed/hidden/removed/...?

Comment: From what I can see there is only one component for each route that is rendered in the default `router-outlet`, I need the value from this one

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: But I don't know how it should be done, that's why I asked the question. What is unclear in the question or the context?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the **ActivatedRoute** indeed.

You need to inject it in your component :

```
contructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And then you need to **listen to route change event**, something like :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        // route info is stored in `params`
        console.log(params);
    });
}
```

Comment: the parameter I need is not passed in URL, it's hardcoded in every component, see edit

Comment: Then it should be done via a Service, doesn't matter that is a very small service. Any communication is done by services in Angular2, just between siblings components can be done through '@Input' - '@Output'

Comment: thank you very much, if you turn it into an answer I'll accept it